# A power series expression for $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^j $

Tags: number-theory, power-series, binomial-coefficients

I know that:

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^j = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty {j+k-1\choose k}z^{j+k} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=1}^m {m-1\choose j-1}\right)z^m $$

and I am now looking for a similar expression for:

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^j $$

and would be grateful for any help (hope it is trivial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^j$ converges for $\Re(z) <0$, there we can use the geometric series to simplify it. You'll find that it is a rational function with only one pole at $z=0$, thus no chance to find a power series expansion at $z=0$ for it. It has a unique Laurent series valid on the whole of $\Re(z) <0$.

Comment: Thanks reuns. Could you maybe share the Laurent series?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\frac{z+1}{1-z}=x$. We have
$$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{z+1}{1-z}\right)^j=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } x^j=\frac{x}{1-x};\;|x|<1$$
Therefore if $\left|\frac{z+1}{1-z}\right|<1\to \text{Re}(z)<0$ the series is
$$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{z+1}{1-z}\right)^j=\frac{\frac{z+1}{1-z}}{1-\frac{z+1}{1-z}}=-\frac{z+1}{2 z};\;\text{Re}(z)<0$$

Comment: probably you meant a $-1$ for the $j=0$ case.

Comment: @Phicar Thank you. This is the main reason why I got $10\%$ less in my exams. In my last written exam in 1982 I lost $4/30$ points for missing a "minus" in a Hamiltonian. And I had the cheatsheet in my pocket!

Comment: Thanks Raffaele (also for the story :-) )